# Association list `Symbol's function definition is void` error

Tags: variables

I am trying to achieve a slightly smart package management in my `init.el` file but can't achieve it because of ELisp ignorance. Here is the case.

```
;; package loader function
(defun load-packages-context-sensitively (plist)
  (dolist (ppack plist) 
    (unless (and ((not window-system) (string= (assoc ppack plist) "GUI")))
      (require '(ppack)))))

(defconst package-assoc-list
  '((package-1 "CLI") ;here
    (package-2 "CLI") ; I 
    (package-3 "GUI") ; declare
    (package-4 "GUI") ; my packages
    (package-5 "CLI")))

(load-packages-context-sensitively (package-assoc-list)) ; here we need a happy ending
```

I simply want to generate an associated list (I'm not even sure if its the right data structure) and map each package name `(provide 'package-x)`'ed in another file to "GUI" and "CLI" strings. What I want to achieve is to pass the list to my slightly-smart-function and prevent GUI packages being loaded in CLI environments...

It gives me `Symbol's function definition is void: package-assoc-list` error now. Yes it looks very self-explanatory, it is well documented but I couldn't find a way to overcome it.

Any help, any correction, any suggestion, any cringe is more than welcome.

Comment: Side note: loading a package should have "no visible effect" (other than defining some functions and variables, that is): any visible effect is usually considered a *bug* (because Emacs sometimes loads packages for rather frivolous reasons).  So most likely you shouldn't be thinking about which packages to load, but about which functionality to enable.

Answer (score 1):

This question is likely a duplicate, but I don't find it now.

You are using `(package-assoc-list)`, which means to invoke the function `package-assoc-list`.  Just use variable `package-assoc-list` instead.

```
(load-packages-context-sensitively package-assoc-list)
```

As @NickD added, in a comment here:

> In addition, the `(require '(ppack))` in the definition of `load-packages-context-sensitively` is wrong I believe: require takes a symbol as argument, not a list.

Comment: In addition, the `(require '(ppack))` in the definition of `load-packages-context-sensitively` is wrong I believe: `require` takes a symbol as argument, not a list.

Comment: @NickD: Duh. I've added that to this answer. If you prefer to add it as another answer, let me know. Thx.